# Java: generics type

Tags: java

Class B extends from class A, and G is generics class. Now -

```
G<X> g = new G<B>();
```

If I'm not wrong, then X can be:

```
? extends A
```

or

```
? super B
```

My question: Why X can't be simply `A`. B extends from A, so that seems correct. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X can't be A because what goes in the generics on the left side must match the generics on the right side. However, by saying X is "? extends A", it tells java that the generic type for g is any class that has at least the functionality of A.

Simply put, G != G, but G can hold either G, G, or anything else that extends A. G means that the generic must be A.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read through the oracle [tutorial on generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html).

The important section is:

> But what about an "animal cage"?
>   English is ambiguous, so to be precise
>   let's assume we're talking about an
>   "all-animal cage":
>
> `Cage<Animal> animalCage = ...;`
>
> This
>   is a cage designed to hold all kinds
>   of animals, mixed together. It must
>   have bars strong enough to hold in the
>   lions, and spaced closely enough to
>   hold in the butterflies. Such a cage
>   might not even be feasible to build,
>   but if it is, then:
>
> `animalCage.add(king);`
>     `animalCage.add(monarch);`
>
> Since a lion
>   is a kind of animal (Lion is a subtype
>   of Animal), the question then becomes,
>   "Is a lion cage a kind of animal cage?
>   Is `Cage<Lion>` a subtype of
>   `Cage<Animal>`?". By the above
>   definition of animal cage, the answer
>   must be "no". This is surprising! But
>   it makes perfect sense when you think
>   about it: A lion cage cannot be
>   assumed to keep in butterflies, and a
>   butterfly cage cannot be assumed to
>   hold in lions. Therefore, neither cage
>   can be considered an "all-animal"
>   cage.

Comment: @Andreas my, you are being harsh today. Bad coffee? :-)

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd - no ;) I put the downvote on the version without the quote and believe, when it became visible, Eric had already improved the answer. Was some sort of multi threading problem (`Andreas_D` thread was working on an old copy of `Erics Answer`;) )

Answer (score 0):

This is done to ensure that you don't accidentally insert an object of type `C` which extends `A` as well.

This works for arrays and issues an `ArrayStoreException` on runtime.